# Concatenar Wheres en un Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Podrían ayudarme a crear una consulta a través de un Procedimiento Almacenado
para seleccionar Ventas con:

- pCliente (solo cuando no sea nulo)
- pProducto (solo cuando no sea nulo)
- pVendedor (solo cuando no sea nulo)
- ListadeVentas( pDesde, pHasta, pCliente, pProducto, pVendedor)

  ```
  ifnull pCliente then cSqlCliente="" else cSqlCliente="and Cliente= pCliente "
  fnull pProducto then cSqlProducto="" else cSqlProducto="and Producto= pProducto "
  ifnull pVendedor then cSqlVendedor="" else cSqlVendedor="and Vendedor= pVendedor "
  cSqlSelect:= "Select * from Ventas where fecha between pDesde and pHasta "+
   cSqlCliente+ 
   cSqlProducto+
   cSqlVendedor
  Exec( cSqlSelect)
  ```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Pueden hacer esto por mí" no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede quedar en un solo `query` sin tener que generar dinámicamente la consulta.

Quedaría más o menos así para cliente pero sería una lógica similar para **N variables**

```
Select * from Ventas where fecha between pDesde and pHasta 
AND 
(
     pCliente is null 
    or  Cliente= pCliente
);
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero ( pCliente is null or Cliente= pCliente ) al ser (pCliente= Null), da verdadero y la consulta sale vacía, la idea es al contrario, si pCliente= Null, me seleccione TODOS los Clientes. Saludos

Luis

Comment: Necesitas volver a validar la lógica, si pCliente=null o Cliente=pCliente... Entonces si es null te va a traer Todos los Clientes.

Comment: Tenias razón!!! Quedo perfecto!!! GRACIAS